# Python in Selenium/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract real estate listing info from a site using selenium and beautiful soup using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ben.sturm/scraping-house-listing-data-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup-1cbb94ba9492

Aim is to gather all the href links from the first page before finding the 'next page' button, navigating to next and collecting all links on that page and so on.

Tried with a single function to achieve this and repeat for each page but can't figure out why it's not working. New to learning code and have seems too trivial to find an answer yet. Would appreciate any help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import regex as re


driver = webdriver.Chrome
url = "http://property.shw.co.uk/searchproperties/Level2-0/Level1-0-181-236-167-165/Units/Development-or-House-and-Flat-or-Investment-or-Land-or-Office-or-Other/UnitIds-0/For-Sale"
driver.get(url)
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "body1")))
    print("Page is Ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("page took too long to load")


def get_house_links(url, driver, pages=3):
    house_links = []
    driver.get(url)
    for i in range(pages):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        listings = soup.find_all("a", class_="L")
        page_data = [row['href'] for row in listings]
        house_links.append(page_data)
        time.sleep(np.random.lognormal(0, 1))
        next_button = soup.find_all("a", class_="pageingBlock darkBorder")
        next_button_link = ['http://property.shw.co.uk'+row['href'] for row in next_button]
        if i < 3:
            driver.get(next_button_link[0])
    return house_links
get_house_links(url, driver)
```

Comment: You need to explain  *not working*, but for starters you don't call `get_house_links()` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Guy, as in the browser does not move to second page and so on. I added: get_house_links(url, driver) and now it goes to the second page but not to the third and final page. Appreciate your help

Comment: Currently it's going to page 1, refreshes that page, then to page 2, then back to 1 and then back to 2 and ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class_="pageingBlock darkBorder"` match the previous page button as well, so `next_button_link[0]` send you back to previous page. You need more precise locator

```
next_button = soup.select('img[src*="propNext"]')
if next_button:
    next_button = next_button[0].find_parent('a')
    next_button_link = 'http://property.shw.co.uk' + next_button['href']
    driver.get(next_button_link)
```

Comment: Thanks again Guy. I'm still getting an error on the href however:
   next_button_link = 'http://property.shw.co.uk' + next_button['href']
   in __getitem__
   return self.attrs[key]
   KeyError: 'href'

Comment: @AlistairKhandy Try with `next_button = soup.select('img[src*="propNext"]')[0].find_parent('a')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot @Guy. Just any idea how to fix this error? next_button = soup.select('img[src*="propNext"]')[0].find_parent('a')
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @AlistairKhandy Is it working or not? are you getting an exception?

Comment: it's navigating through the pages and scraping the links fine however will not run driver.close() at the end and shows the index error above on the log

Comment: @AlistairKhandy You can check if the list is not empty, update my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Guy! Very grateful for all of your help, it works perfectly now.